# Не работает Destroy() в unity 2d c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Просмотрел кучу разных вопросов в интернете, которые как-либо были связаны с Destroy() и не нашёл решение своей проблемы.
В общем, при соприкосновении коллизий 2-х объектов (К обоим привязан RigidBody2d и BoxCollider2d, но у одного из них стоит галочка на IsTrigger), код срабатывает, но не удаляет объект.

```
public class Coll : MonoBehaviour{
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
       print(other.name);
       Destroy(other);
   }  
}
```

Данный код привязан к объекту, который представляет собой триггер, при касании к которому, объект должен исчезнуть вовсе.
В консоль выводится название объекта, которое вошло в коллизию, но оно не удаляется. Консоль по этому поводу молчит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете `Destroy` по отношению к коллайдеру, а не к объекту.

Попробуйте так:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сидел часа 2 и не мог понять, в чём же дело)
При чём, вчера всё работало, а сегодня перестало, хотя я мало что изменил)